# php regex find word in string

Tags: php

PHP Regex find specif url in string i want to find

**stackoverflow.site**

**'stackoverflow.site' in my string.** later i will replace with my own url

```
$string='Regular expressions are a powerful tool for examining http://www.stackoverflow.site/uploads/2008/07/22/feldbalz-by-gus-wustemann-17.jpg and modifying text. Regular expressions themselves, with a general pattern notation almost like a mini programming language, allow you to describe and parse text. They enable you to search for patterns within a string, extracting matches http://www.stackoverflow.site/uploads/2008/07/22/feldbalz-by-gus-wustemann-squ1.jpg flexibly and precisely. However, you should note that because regular expressions are more powerful, they are also slower than the more basic string functions. You should only use regular expressions if you have http://www.stackoverflow.site/uploads/2008/07/22/feldbalz-by-gus-wustemann-12.jpg a particular need.
This tutorial gives a brief overview of http://www.stackoverflow.site/uploads/2008/07/22/feldbalz-by-gus-wustemann-2.jpg basic regular expression syntax and then considers the functions that PHP provides for working with regular expressions.';

$find='[http://www.stackoverflow.site/uploads/]';
```

Comment: regex only for stackoverflow.site not other

Comment: this looks kind of shady ... to say the least :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-quote.php) to automatically escape special characters in regex

```
$find='http://www.stackoverflow.site/uploads/';
$rfind=preg_quote($find);
preg_replace($rfind, "mysite", $input_lines);
```

Comment: Again; why use regex when you're just doing literal string replacement? If you really want to ruin performance I'd suggest using an online webservice to do regex replacements that runs on a computer from 1998. Perhaps add a few `sleep()`'s in there too.